How does the transformer model's attention mechanism deal with differing sequence lengths?
I am going through the architecture of the transformer and its attention mechanism. The thing I don't get about this mechanism is how it handles sequences of different lengths. For example:
How does the attention mechanism handle shorter sequences compared to longer ones?
Any special preprocessing necessary for sequences of unequal lengths?
How does padding impact the attention calculations, and is there a standard way to handle padding with transformer models?
All explanations or references to examples would be very useful!
references:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762
https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/
